# Bean named 'mailService' is expected to be of type 'grails.plugins.mail.MailService' but was actually of type 'eafya.MailService'

Tags: grails

I am working on email configuration for my web app and am getting this error `

> Bean named 'mailService' is expected to be of type 'grails.plugins.mail.MailService' but was actually of type 'eafya.MailService'

I have included `compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0'`in my build.gradle with no success.

My code for my EmailService:

```
package eafya
import grails.plugin.asyncmail.AsynchronousMailService
import grails.plugin.mail.MailService
class EmailService {

   MailService mailService
        def groovyPageRenderer
        def grailsApplication

    /**
     * Sends the email to given email id
     */
    def sendMail(MailDTO mailDTO) {

        log.info "Sending Mail To ==== ${mailDTO?.toMailId}"

        mailService.sendMail {
            async true
            to mailDTO?.toMailId
            subject mailDTO.subject
            html mailDTO.content
        }
    }
    /*
        * Sends the reset password email
        */
    def sendResetPasswordEmail(Patient user, Token token) {
        MailDTO mailDTO = new MailDTO()
        mailDTO.with {
            toMailId = user?.email
            subject = "Password reset on Mobile Career Index"
            content = groovyPageRenderer.render(template: '/mail/resetPassword', model: [user: user,token:token])
        }
        sendMail(mailDTO)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The full class name in the import for `MailService` is `grails.plugin.mail.MailService`, but as the error message says, the correct class is `grails.plugins.mail.MailService`. Groovy ignores invalid imports, so it's as if there's no import statement at all and the compiler expects it to be in the same package as `EmailService`. Change the import to:

```
import grails.plugins.mail.MailService
```

Comment: I omitted the type, the import is okay without success.Any more suggestions that you may have in mind?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you had an import statement. I updated the answer.

Comment: Well, copied and pasted the import statement and am still stuck with the same error message.

Comment: Try running `grails clean`. If that doesn't work consider omitting the type (change to `def mailService`) since Groovy doesn't need to know the type and there's not much benefit in declaring the type for this bean.

Comment: Unfortunately `grails clean` doesn't do the magic. In addition, changed the type to `def mailService` but the error message still persists.

Comment: That's clearly not possible if you're not defining the type.

Comment: Is there a way I can use just the controller rather than the service?

Comment: @Georgiadis, if you've changed your snippet in your testing, please make the change Burt suggests (adding an "s" to make it "plugins" in the import), and let us know if the error is still exactly the same.

Comment: @billjamesdev, I have applied the "s" in the import as suggested by Burt but unfortunately, the error still is the same.